# What are $a$ and $a^*$ called in the context of a classical harmonic oscillator?

Tags: terminology, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a harmonic oscillator defined by the coupled differential equations
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\dot{X} &= \omega Y \\
\dot{Y} &= - \omega X \, .
\end{split} \tag{1}
\end{align}
Defining new variables $a = X + i Y$ and $a^* = X - i Y$, produces a new uncoupled system of equations
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\dot{a} &= - i \omega \, a \\
\dot{a}^* &= i \omega \, a^* \, . 
\end{split} \tag{2}
\end{align}

In *classical* physics [1] (or just in the mathematical context of this transformation used to solve a pair of coupled differential equations) what are the variables *a* and $a^*$ called?

[1]: In the context of quantum mechanics, the variables $a$ an $a^*$ would in fact be operators and would be called the "raising" and "lowering" operators.

Comment: Aren't they canonical variables; at least this is the term I was familiar with when decoupling differential equations. Those, though, were generally not complex, so I wonder if the usage of $i$ here changes that?

Comment: I think your equations 3 & 4 are incorrect. Shouldn't they have an $i$ out front with the $\omega$?

Comment: Also, the raising and lowering operators are non-hermetian, so why should we expect these classical variables to have any meaning. In the classical context, $Y$ would be momentum, so adding position to complex momentum doesn't make sense dimensionally.

Comment: @Geoffrey In the course of getting to the starting form Daniel suggests you multiply the position and momentum by constants so that $X$ and $Y$ have the same units (otherwise the initial expressions would also be dimensionally inconsistent). Alas that confuses the issue of interpretation.

Comment: Daniel, it might help the discussion to exhibit the transformation for some specific system (mass on a spring?), though I admit that risks contaminating the resulting interpreation with the specifics of that particular system.

Comment: A few months ago I learned how to number *groups* of equations, and I thought it might be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

I would call $a$ and $a^*$ the complex amplitude of the oscillator. Or I guess $a$ is the complex amplitude itself and $a^*$ is the complex conjugate of the amplitude but the distinction is unimportant as they carry the same information (just like in the quantum case).

Comment: There is a simple way to figure out what $a$ and $a^*$ are: express the observable things for the oscillator via these "complex amplitudes". To be rigorous - this is the only right way of "seeing" their true meaning.

Comment: In phase space quantization, where they are c-numbers instead of operators, they are called complex phase space amps, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I would call them [normal modes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode), which are by definition the degrees of freedom of a system that oscillate at a single frequency.

Beyond terminology there is a whole body of classical theory behind this term making it useful, for example for more complex oscillators or continuous oscillating fields.